# Image within a ng-repeat displayed in a row instead of in a column

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm using ng-repeat to display some images. I think this is more of a CSS issue, but I'm not sure.

```
<div ng-repeat="hex in hexRow track by hex.id">
    <img ng-src="{{hex.img}}"/>
</div>
```

[image]

How do I display them in row rather than in column (there is no CSS style assigned to them atm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using div tag as container which is block element. Thats why they are coming in column

Comment: Thanks, I used <span> instead and... well it works of course.